# Same circuit but different results

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise

To measure a 440VAC voltage, I am using a 2ma/2ma transformer. In the PCB I am using 3 exactly the same circuits to measure voltage in a three phase system.

To test the circuit, I measured output of the Op-Ams  (`U2`, `U3`, `U4`) with `FLUKE 190-504SCOPEMETER` oscilloscope after removing the transformers. I observe a sine wave noise of 12.5 kHz (approx.) is introduced at an amplitude of 100 mV (approx.) at the output of the first and third op-amps. The output of the second op-amp doesn't show any noise.

In the following, I am providing the circuit diagram and the oscilloscope screenshots.

The schematic and the PCB design are available at the following links.

Full project:

https://oshwlab.com/sigrama/centinela-tester-20211026_copy_copy_copy_copy_copy_copy_copy_copy_copy

Schematic:

https://easyeda.com/editor#id=4f510cbb25b741928b9f75deb0f9c3a4

PCB:

https://easyeda.com/editor#id=cfa50c9e8d6349088ce558d5928b9370

Oscilloscope's screenshots

Voltage measured at the Output (`PIN 1`) of `U2`

[image: U2 output with AC coupling]

[image: U2 output with DC coupling]

Voltage measured at the Output (`PIN 1`) of `U3`

[image: U3 output with AC coupling]

[image: U3 output with DC coupling]

Voltage measured at the Output (`PIN 1`) of `U4`

[image: U4 output with AC coupling]

[image: U4 output with DC coupling]

Please help me understand where does the noise originate and why is it not showing up at the output of the `U3`.

Comment: 12.5kHz sounds like it could be oscillation due to insufficient op-amp power bypass capacitors, or excessive output capacitance.  Try soldering a leaded 0.1uF polyester cap directly across the opamp's + and - power pins.

Comment: @rdtsc, I have a 0.1uF capacitor already. Do you want me to connect another one?

Comment: @rdtsc, Regarding output capacitance, I have a `100ohm` resistor in series before connecting a load of `33nF` capacitor.